# EFI - GPT dual-boot quantal AMD64 - impossible boot windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, gpt

I tried to install Ubuntu Quantal AM64 on a EFI - GPT notebook (asus X501U) in dualboot.
Ubuntu works fine, but i can't boot windows anymore.
HDD is partitioned in this way:
sda1     0.2   Gb        boot efi
sda2     0.128 Gb
sda3     60    Gb        Windows
sda4     210   Gb        Data
sda5     15    Gb        Ubuntu
sda6     4     Gb        swap
sda7     25    Gb        recovery image
Booting pc, grub2 runs, but if i try to select "windows 7 loader on sda3" i receive this message:
"error: invalid EFI file path." 
If i select "windows recovery Environment on sda7" i receive: "error: impossible find command "drivemap" - error: invalid EFI file path."

I installed dualboot ubuntu many times, but this is the first time on a EFI - GPT system.

---

This is the Boot repair scan log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1320178/

I think easyBCD (win utility) could have corrupted something, after used it i understood it was not compatible with EFI GPT.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need, [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) will fix it for you

Comment: After boot-repair, i have in my grub2 menu a new option: "windows UEFI loader", but if i select it i receive: "windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem... ... file: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD status: 0xc0000098, the windows boot configuration data file does not contain a valid OS entry". If i select windows 7 in grub2, nothing changed.

Comment: The error you report after running Boot-Repair is a Windows-specific issue. You may want to try booting your Windows install disc and running its repair tools, or posting on a Windows forum. It's also possible that your Windows installation has been damaged (say, by a partitioning error), but more detailed partitioning data would be required to diagnose this problem -- something like the output of [Boot Info Script.][1]


  [1]: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Comment: Please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

Comment: Boot-Repair doesn't help at all with a UEFI/GPT setup, I've tried it many times as have lots of others on the forums. The last I checked it was still impossible to get Win7/8 and Ubuntu 12.xx dual booting from a single drive in most UEFI/GPT based systems, the only solution I know of is to install to separate drives and use the motherboards boot menu to make your selection as Grub cannot handle UEFI/GPT correctly when more than one operating system is installed, with some motherboards even this doesn't work and obviously it isn't an option for most laptops/notebooks unless you install one OS t

Answer (score 0):

You have to Convert Ubuntu into Legacy mode.

First create  [Boot-Repair Disc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)  Or Install boot-repair tool

Start Boot-Repair Disk or boot-repair tool

Click on `Advanced options`

Go to the `GRUB location` tab.

Untick the `Separate /boot/efi partition` option

Click the `Apply` button.

After install grub again on /dev/sda , it will detect Windows and create entry for it.
You will be able to see its entry on boot up.

Comment: i receive this alert: "found GPT. Create a partition BIOS-Boot or try separate /boot/efi partition"